# Different types of users in one table, How to add data off different users

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have 5 type of users:

- Super Admin
- Coordinator
- Supervisor
- Student
- External Examiner

All of them have some common attributes like `ID`, `name`, `email` etc. I have inserted them in one table `user` differentiating them with `user_type` attribute.

I have also made different tables for each user like `Coordinator`, `Student` because each user have different attributes.

My Question is:

> if I want to add a coordinator user into table, I can add it into user table with `user_type=Coordinator` but how will I link this coordinator from `user` table into 'coordinator' table?

Can anyone provide me with PHP-MySQL code for it?

Comment: Are you just asking about foreign key?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: Yes, for example i am adding a Coordinator in 'user ' table how can i link it to 'coordinator' table in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
( `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `user_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   user_type int 1,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`userid`) 
); 

CREATE TABLE `user_type`
( `user_typeid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_type` VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_typeid`) 
); 

CREATE TABLE `tbl_corordinator`
( `coordinator_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id int 1,
  `field1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`coordinator_id`)
);
```

When you will add 'Coordinator' users in `users` table, you need to add information in  `tbl_corordinator` & you will add `userid` (which is the primary key of `users` table.)

Thus using this foreign key concept, you can achieve this relation.

Comment: Not bad but I don't see any `foreign key` defined.

Comment: I have missed that.You need to declare add foreign key tbl_corordinator if  engine is INNODB & otherwise we need to use conceptual foreign key